# Access is denied when debugging Process.Start from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
var chromePath = @"C:\""Program Files(x86)""\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
Process.Start(chromePath);
```

I was debugging in Visual Studio as **Administrator**. But still got the exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.
```

What could go wrong? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is misleading. The path is incorrect. Removing the double quotes and putting a space between Files and (x86) fixes it.

Try this:

```
        var chromePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        Process.Start(chromePath);
```